# QT Designer window not opening in Pycharm

Tags: python, user-interface, pycharm, qt-designer

I am trying to import a GUI into Pycharm from QT Designer however I cannot get it to open a window even though there are no errors.

The two ways I have tried are;
1st: QT Designer offers "Python" code via "Form>View Python Code" which provides the following code. On a side note; a number of the PySide2 modules listed to import are greyed out and I've tried running with them included and after taking them out with no success.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

################################################################################
## Form generated from reading UI file 'untitledxADjFi.ui'
##
## Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.14.1
##
## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################

from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter, QPixmap,
    QRadialGradient)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1107, 899)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(u"textEdit")
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QRect(10, 340, 381, 501))
        self.textBrowser = QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName(u"textBrowser")
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QRect(420, 340, 331, 501))
        self.textBrowser_2 = QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName(u"textBrowser_2")
        self.textBrowser_2.setGeometry(QRect(780, 340, 311, 501))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 1107, 22))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

**2nd:** Via Pycharm, I can use the external tool for PyUIC to have it create a copy as a .py file with the following code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.2
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1107, 899)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 340, 381, 501))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 340, 331, 501))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 340, 311, 501))
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1107, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
```

As I said above, both of these run with the result of `Process finished with exit code 0`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start the application. Currently you are only defining how it should look like.
The methods inside the class are never called.

Maybe this code may help you: (copied from: https://pythonbasics.org/qt-designer-python/)
helloworld is the name of the ui file. And this code is inside a new file.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys
import helloworld

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, helloworld.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ExampleApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = ExampleApp()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you! I started with the hello world with python but never realized I wasn't actually calling it.